# Fourier series - if it’s not an odd function, how does shifting affects my calculation?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The function $f(t)$ given in the graph for $-4 \le t < 4 $
[image]

this is the function of - $$f(t) = \begin{cases} -1,  0< t \le 1 \\ 0 , -1 < t \le 0 \end{cases} $$

I am told to determine the Fourier series for $f(t)$ and state the first three non-zero terms.

I assumed this function to be odd, however, read on to find out why I feel that I might be wrong.

Since $f(t)$ is odd , $a_0 = 0 , a_n = 0$

The period of the function- $-1$ to $1$

Therefore $L = 2/2 = 1$

since it’s odd, I used this formula-

$$b_n =\frac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{L} {f(t) \sin {\frac{\pi n t}{L}} } dt $$

And I got $$b_n = \frac{1}{n\pi} (\cos (n\pi) -1)$$

I calculated $b_1$ to $b_5$ to determine the first 3 non zero terms.

$b_1 = \frac{-2}{\pi} $

$b_2, b_4= 0$

$b_3 = \frac{-2}{3\pi} $

$b_5 = \frac{-2}{5 \pi} $

Here’s a sample calculation:

$b_1 = \frac{1}{\pi} ( \cos (\pi) -1) = \frac{1}{\pi} (-1-1) = \frac{-2}{\pi}

Therefore $f(t) = \frac{-2}{\pi} \sin (\pi t) - \frac{2}{3 \pi} \sin (3\pi t) - \frac{2}{5\pi} \sin (5\pi t) ...... $

Now, after finding out that this function is an odd function as the ‘middle’ of an odd function needs to be $0$ , I performed a shift. - here’s a picture of it as I am not too sure on how to put it in words...
[image]

Basically I performed a shift to make the original function to be centred at 0 by shifting up by $\frac{1}{2} $

Now, how would this affect my calculation for $b_n$ ? Would it affect it ?

For the $b_n$ value ? Must I subtract $\frac{1}{2} $ ? meaning the new value of $b_n$ is -

$$\frac{1}{n\pi} (\cos (n\pi) -1) - \frac{1}{2} $$
Which also means that from $b_1$ to $b_5$, my answer has to be all deducted by $\frac{1}{2} $ which means I will have no non zero terms from $b_1$ to $b_3$ . How would my $f(t)$ function change ?

Also, how do I plot the discrete amplitude spectrum of f(t) up to the third harmonic ?

Thanks..

Comment: A function is odd iff $f(-x)=-f(x)$. Try $x=0.5$: $f(-0.5)=0\neq 1=-(f(0.5))$, which implies that the function is not odd. Indeed, if you were to perform the vertical shift (which is simply $\tilde{f}:=f+\frac12$ then $\tilde{f}$ would be an odd function, and using linearity of the Fourier transform you could obtain the Fourier transform of $f$.

Comment: @b00nheT do u mean that my steps are correct if the centre is 0 ? However, it’s not. So I have to subtract $1/2$ for all my values of b ? Meaning the new f(t) is $ \frac{-5}{2\pi} \sin (\pi t) - \frac{1}{2} \sin (2 \pi t) - \frac{7}{6\pi} \sin (3\pi t) $ ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot out of order here.

The function is not odd, and the period is not $1$.

I suggest you start again from square one and compute the $a_n$ and $b_n$, using the formulas in your textbook.

Concerning shifts: Vertical shifts of $f$ only affect $a_0$. The effect of horizontal shifts on the Fourier coefficients is described by a simple formula, but this formula involves the so called *complex Fourier coefficients* $\ c_k$ $(k\in{\mathbb Z})$.

Comment: The function is neither odd Nor even and I tried to make the function odd by performing a vertical shift of $\frac{-1}{2}$ . I am not too sure about how this $1/2$ would affect the $b_n$ , $b_1$ , etc.